# Domain-wide delegation with impersonation

Tags: google-workspace, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

My scenario involves two service accounts, namely S1 and S2.
S2 was granted domain-wide access to a Google Workspace.

I'd like to have S1 impersonate S2 (already have the "Service Account Token Creator role" on S1) and use its permissions to retrieve some information regarding Google Workspace using S2's access.

Is it possible to delegate authority to S1?

Edit:
Johannes Passing solution did the trick, still feels like somewhat of a workaround, opened an issue on [google-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/2011) to add such a functionality.

Comment: what is S1 S2? are you talking about two different service accounts?  As long as the service account credentials were created on the domain account you can set up delegation.

Comment: @DaImTo - updated the question I hope it clarifies things.

S1 and S2 are indeed two different service accounts, S1 has "Service Account Token Creator role" permissions on S2 and S2 has domain-wide access to a Google Workspace.

Comment: As far as I know delegation must be preformed on a user on the domain.  I dont think you can delegate to another service account.   That being said did you try what happened?  What is the issue you are having?

Comment: I was able to use S2 with a delegation to a user.  
I was also able to use S1 and impersonate S2.  
I wasn't able to combine both steps -   
1. S1 impersonate S2  
2. delegate to a user

Comment: I have not personally tried this, but Google supports a delegation chain. You must specify the three accounts at the same time while delegating. S1 -> S2 -> User. You must specify S2 in the delegation chain when you set up impersonation. In otherwords, S1 impersonates User by declaring S2 in the delegation chain.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks on the reply, tried using [generateAccessToken](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken) which indeed supports delegation chain, it does not seem to support a user as a link in the chain as far as I could tell....

Comment: I recommend editing your question and showing your code and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, that's possible](https://jpassing.com/2022/01/15/using-domain-wide-delegation-on-google-cloud-without-service-account-keys/) if S2's client ID has been configured for domain-wide delegation:

1. [Create a JWT assertion](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) with:

   - `iss` set to S2's email address
   - `sub` set to the Workspace user's email address
   - `scope` set to the scopes you whitelisted for S2's client ID and domain-wide delegation
2. As S1, call [projects.serviceAccounts.signJwt](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signJwt) on S2 to sign the assertion with S2's key. As a result, you get a signed JWT assertion. For this to work, S1 must have the *Service Account Token Creator* role on S2.
3. Post the assertion to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`. As a result, you get an access token for the Workspace user.