# Domain wide delegation with default credentials in Cloud Run

Tags: go, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-run

In golang I'd like to use default service account credentials provided by Cloud Run to create delegated credentials (domain-wide delegation), specifically to invoke the Drive API as the user.  I've got this working when the credentials are obtained from a json file, but not when provided by Cloud Run.  I had the same problem in Python and followed [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/blob/main/examples/gce-to-adminsdk) to solve it, but am not sure how to do this in go.

Code example (gin handler) that works when loading from JSON file (service account key with domain-wide delegation) but not when deriving credentials from Cloud Run:

```
email := "user@mydomain.com"
params := google.CredentialsParams{
    Scopes:  []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"},
    Subject: email}
creds, credErr := google.FindDefaultCredentialsWithParams(c, params)
if credErr != nil {
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("Unable to create credentials as %v: %v", email, credErr)
    fmt.Println(msg)
    c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, msg)
    return
}

// CREATE DRIVE SERVICE
client := oauth2.NewClient(c, creds.TokenSource)
driveService, driveErr := drive.NewService(c, option.WithHTTPClient(client))
if driveErr != nil {
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("Unable to retrieve Drive client: %v", driveErr)
    fmt.Println(msg)
    c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, msg)
    return
}

// List Files
r, listErr := driveService.Files.List().PageSize(10).Do()
if listErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(listErr)
}
fmt.Printf("Received %v files\n", len(r.Files))
for _, i := range r.Files {
    fmt.Println(i.Name)
}
c.String(http.StatusOK, "Ok")
return
```

When I run this from JSON file, it lists the ten file names from user@mydomain.com.  When I run this in Cloud Run (without including the JSON file in the container), it doesn't find any files, and I believe this is because the credentials are not user credentials, but rather service account credentials without access to any files.

Comment: Did you try to use a custom service account in the Cloud Run service configuration? Default service account can't be domain wide (they doesn't belong to your organisation, but to Google Cloud!)

Comment: No, considering that domain wide delegation works when using a json file/key from a default service account, didn’t think it would matter.

Comment: Also the default service accounts don’t belong to google, they are from my project.  Regardless, I did create a custom service account and deployed cloud run to run as that account.  Same result, when running from json it actually obtains a user cred, when running in cloud run it lists drive files as the service account not as the delegated user.

Answer (score 2):

To use domain-wide delegation without a service account key you have to:

1. [Create a JWT assertion](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) for impersonating a user
2. Call [projects.serviceAccounts.signJwt](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signJwt) on a service account that's configured for domain-wide delegation to sign the assertion
3. Exchange the signed assertion against an access token

[This blog post](https://jpassing.com/2022/01/15/using-domain-wide-delegation-on-google-cloud-without-service-account-keys/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70232852/domain-wide-delegation-with-impersonation/70252736#) have more details.

Comment: This is helpful.  Was hoping for golang examples but believe I can follow these steps to reproduce the same in go.  Thank you.